# I am looking for a way to use both "In-Cell" and "Popup" editing for a Kendo Grid

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, popup, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I would like for the "Popup" editing to occur when a new record is added and for the "InCell" to be for all other editing. I saw examples on here of ways to accomplish this with "Popup" and "InLine" but have not seen any solutions of how to achieve what I am trying to do. My Kendo Grid is located within a Kendo Popup Window and I can get the "Popup" editor to open but only for a quick second before the parent Popup Window gets called. I have read that this is being called because the child popup window is updating the parent popup window. My thought process was to call the Kendo read() as a onClose event of the child window to update the parent window. I would appreciate any help or if anyone could point me in the right direction. Here is my Grid on the parent popup window.

```
        @(Html.Kendo().Grid<DAX.Models.CsvSubmittal>()
            .Name("CsvGrid")
            .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:800px; margin-top:-90px" })
            .Columns(column =>
            {
                column.Bound(p => p.CsvSubmittalID).Hidden();
                column.Bound(p => p.SpecSection).Title("Spec Section").Width(100).Format("{0:000000}");
                column.Bound(p => p.SpecTitle).Title("Spec Title").Width(150);
                column.Bound(p => p.SubmittalDescription).Title("Submittal Description").Width(200);
                column.Bound(p => p.Subcontractor).Title("Subcontractor").Width(150);

                column.Bound(p => p.SubmissionDueDate).Title("Due Date").Width(100)
                    .ClientTemplate("#= SubmissionDueDateTemplate(SubmissionDueDate) #");

                column.Bound(p => p.ReviewCompleteDate).Title("Complete Date").Width(100)
                    .ClientTemplate("#= ReviewDateTemplate(ReviewCompleteDate) #").Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}");

                column
                    .Template(@<text></text>).Width(90)

                    .ClientTemplate("<div style='text-align:center; cursor:pointer '><a class=ActionbuttonDelete onclick=\"MyDeleteTemplate('#=CsvSubmittalID#')\">[Delete]</a></div>");  
            })

                .Reorderable(reorder => reorder.Columns(false))
                .Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))
                .Scrollable(scrolling => scrolling.Enabled(true))   
                .Navigatable()
                .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell).CreateAt(GridInsertRowPosition.Bottom))
                    .ToolBar(toolbar =>
                    {
                        toolbar.Custom().Text("Add New Record").Name("popup").HtmlAttributes(new { style = "font-size: 0.95em", id="popup" })/*.Url(Url.Action("CreateRow", "Project", new { projID = Model.ProjectID }))*/;
                        toolbar.Save();
                    })

            .DataSource(datasource => datasource
                                .Ajax()
                                .ServerOperation(false)

                                //.Create(create => create.Action("CreateCsvRow", "Project", new { id = @Model.ProjectID }))

                                .Read(read => read.Action("GetCsvFileData", "Project", new { projectID = @Model.ProjectID }).Type(HttpVerbs.Get))
                                .Update(update => update.Action("UpdateCsvFileData", "Project", new { csvSubmittalID = @Model.CsvSubmittalID }))
                                //.Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("DeleteCsvRow", "Project", new { csvSubmittalID = @Model.CsvSubmittalID }))
                                .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.CsvSubmittalID))

                                )
)
```

Here is my javascript function:

```
   var myGrid = $('#CsvGrid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource;

$("#popup").on("click", function () {

    var grid = $("#CsvGrid").data("kendoGrid");

    $(".k-grid-popup", grid.element).on("click", function () {
        debugger;
        grid.options.editable = "popup";
        grid.addRow();
        grid.options.editable = "incell";
    });
});


function onClose(e)
{
    myGrid.read();
}
```

I've seen this accomplished with "Popup" and "InLine". Not sure why all of the difficulty with this alternate combination. If there is any way to disable all listeners on the parent Popup then maybe I could succeed in allowing the user to fill out the new record and then calling the read() afterwards....

Answer (score 1):

I finally submitted a support ticket with Telerik and the response was...

"The Grid can use only one of its built-in editing modes and switching them on the fly is not supported, unless you use setOptions(), which is not really an option in this case, as it will recreate the Grid at an inappropriate time."

and the only way to achieve what I was attempting was to....

"Hack the Grid to use two edit modes at the same time. I will show you how to do it, but keep in mind that we do not claim this will work in all scenarios or with future Kendo UI versions, and you may use this approach at your own risk."

I was then given the following algorithm...

- set the editable mode to "inline"
- use a custom toolbar button for the "Add new record" command - you already have it.
- the custom button will open a generic Kendo UI Window with a custom edit form inside.
- when the form is submitted, use the Grid dataSource API to add/insert the new dataItem
- execute the Grid's saveChanges method

I have attempted something similar but have opted out of implementing this functionality in my situation due to future updates conflicting with my work around. Hopefully this will help someone who might find themselves in the same situation.